# How does neural networks create a boundary in case of more than 3 classes?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification

I understand that a neural network is a universal function approximator, meaning that it can learn to approximate any function that maps inputs to outputs. For a classification task, it creates a boundary line that separates different classes of inputs. For a simple case like the AND gate, it is easy to see how it creates that boundary and makes decisions based on it. But I can’t imagine how that works in a complex case like handwritten digit recognition.Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Suppose you have a training dataset of grayscale images of fixed size, say 28x28, then it's a function from $[256]^{28\times28}$ to $\lbrace 1, 2,..., 9 \rbrace$. If images are not of same size, you may need some more advanced type of neural networks, like CNN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is twofold.

1. Technically it is possible to create these decision boundaries for hand-drawn digits. The problem is the input size is too large. You have `784` pixel for the hand-drawn digit set. But you only have an `x` and `y` axis. So which pixels would you want to put on the axis?
   As you can see in this example form the scikit documentation:

[image]
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_iris_dtc.html

It is possible to generate these decision boundaries for the Iris dataset even tho in contains 3 classes. But here we only use two input variables.
It is not like for hand-drawn digits these decision boundaries do not exist, but rather we can not visualize them because they exist in such a high-dimensional space.

2. The intuition with a decision boundary works very well when you try to separate between two classes because you only need to predict a single value `1` or `0` or `True` or `False`. These Neural Networks require only a single output neuron that produces this classification.

In the case of hand-written digits you need to differentiate between 10 digits, hence the neural network requires 10 output neurons (you could technically get away with 9).

So the first output is responsible for the first digit (`0`). The second neuron is responsible for the second digit (`1`) and so on.
Each individual neuron "makes" a simple prediction is the input image showing the digit I am assigned to.
In the case of the first output neuron, it would decide whether the image shows a `0` or not. So the decision boundary for the first output neuron would just highlight the boundary for "being a `0`" or "being not a `0`".

The same goes for all other output neurons and their assigned digit.
So each output neuron, and hence each digit, receives its own decision boundary if you will.

**However**, in the case of the digits the neurons should not necessarily be independent. If the first neuron predicts the image to be a `0`, then technically it is also possible for other neurons to also predict their assigned digit. So both the neuron for `0` and `7` could at the same time predict that the image is shown a `0` and `7`. We use a special softmax function on the output neurons, that (tries) ensure that these cases do not happen. In this cases, you could, in theory, highlight the decision boundary, if we were able to see in 784 dimensions.

Comment: This answer seems to see the problem as there being more than two features in the MNIST digits. That makes it difficult to visualize, sure, but the set given in my answer applies to any number of dimensions in the feature space.

Comment: Yes, I think we are giving answers to two very distinct questions, and reading your answer I see that the OP might have actually asked for something different from what I believed his question was.

But I also think your answer is quite convoluted, for the point you are trying to make.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty secret about neural networks is that they do no classification. Neural networks create predictions on a continuum. It is common to use a classification rule that makes a predicted category of the category with the highest score on a continuum, but this is a second step, distinct from the neural network. In fact, when the outcome in binary, varying this decision rule is how we wind up with ROC and PR curves.

With that in mind, this is just a mapping between some feature space and another space, typically $[0, 1]^K$ for $K$ categories, where the predicted values (such as from a softmax function) loosely have an interpretation as the probability of membership in the corresponding category. Assuming some conditions that seem typical to assume, the usual universal approximation theorems apply.

If you want to apply decision boundaries from the decision rule of taking the category with the highest prediction, this is the subspace of the feature space that maps to outputs such that the output for some category is higher than the output for the other categories. In math, letting $N_K$ be the neural network output for category $K$ and $\mathcal{X}$ be the feature space, the space of feature values corresponding to category $K$ scoring highest and being predicted as the most likely category is $
\left\{
x\in\mathcal{X}\mid
N_K(x) > N_L(x) \space\forall \space L\ne K
\right\}
$. This space might not be connected. This space might not be convex.

For the MNIST digits, this space $\mathcal{X}$ will be hundreds of dimensions, so instructive examples use feature spaces of two dimensions to allow for visualization, but the math is the same either way.

As an example of the MNIST digits to give the space corresponding to a classification of the digit as seven:

$$
\left\{
x\in\left\{[0, 255]\cap\mathbb Z\right\}^{784}\mid
N_7(x) > N_L(x) \space\forall \space L\ne 7
\right\}
$$

> This is the space of $784$-vectors with integer components between zero and $255$ such that the neural network output value predicted for category seven is greater than the neural network output value predicted for any of the other categories.

(This "classification" would be according to the classification rule that assigns a category according to the category predicted with the highest value. While there are other possible classification rules, this is so common for problems like MNIST digit recognition that I am comfortable using such language.)

Answer (score 0):

At risk of being pedantic, "it can learn to approximate any function that maps inputs to outputs" on compact support. That is to say, neural nets can interpolate but not extrapolate. For example if the activations are RELU then the asymptotic behaviour is linear, even if the training data is drawn from a population whose asymptotic behaviour is exponential.

This is hardly surprising: no finite training set can really provide evidence of asymptotic behaviour.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question. If you disagree, could you please clarify how it answers the question?

Comment: No, very true. It relates to a common inexact statement made in the question.

Comment: Should this, then, be a comment?